# Using async/await: await returns too early

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await, progress-bar

I have a simly Windows Forms app with just a button and a progressbar on it.

Then I have this code:

```
private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar.Maximum = 5;
    progressBar.Step = 1;
    progressBar.Value = 0;

    await ConvertFiles();
    MessageBox.Show("ok");
}

private async Task ConvertFiles()
{
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.PerformStep()));
        }
    });
}
```

The `await ConvertFiles();` returns too early, the ok messagebox already appears at about 80% progress.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you were to run this code synchronously, would the progress bar work correctly?

Comment: You will definitely want to swap your Sleep for `await Task.Delay`

Comment: I can reproduce that. I also tried `progressBar.Value = i`. Is it possible that the implementation of `ProgressBar` has some latency in updating the ui? I checked the sources and it uses `SendMessage` which should be synchronous....very interesting question.

Comment: @RenéVogt With similar issues, I had to increment/decrement/increment the current value. Ollie should try and see if this workaround would produce the desired result.

Comment: @Alex: You mean progressBar.Value++, then progressBar.Value--, then again progressBar.Value++? Does not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is not related to the `async/await`, which you use correctly. The `await` is not returning too early, just the progress bar updates too late. In other words, this is a progress bar control specific problem described in a several threads - [Disabling .NET progressbar animation when changing value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332616/disabling-net-progressbar-animation-when-changing-value), [Disable WinForms ProgressBar animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834761/disable-winforms-progressbar-animation), [The RunWorkerCompleted is triggered before the progressbar reaches 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570486/the-runworkercompleted-is-triggered-before-the-progressbar-reaches-100) etc. You can use one of the workarounds provided in those threads.

Comment: You are right. This helps: Invoke(new Action(() => {                  progressBar.Maximum = 101; progressBar.Value = 101;                   progressBar.Maximum = 100; progressBar.Value = 100; }));

Answer (score 0):

Just to be safe why not move the

```
MessageBox.Show("ok");
```

into a Continuewith so:

```
            await ConvertFiles().ContinueWith((t) => { MessageBox.Show("ok"); });
```

this makes sure it only runs when the task is complete